# JQuery challenge - draw tally marks on click event

Tags: jquery, css

**The Challenge:**
Assign a click event to something which will draw a tally mark inside a container. The tally mark should respect other tally marks already drawn so the positioning of the tally marks makes sense. After every click, tally marks should represent total number of clicks thus far.

These are tally marks:

```
1       2          3              4                 5
▼       ▼          ▼              ▼                 ▼
```

[image: Tally marks example]

The following example has a tally mark count of 83: 
[image]

**Challenge Rules:**

- Must use JQuery & HTML 5.
- Tally marks must be added to a container, not the body.
- The container where you draw the tallies must grow to accommodate new tallies.
- Sprite or CSS3 for the actual tick mark is up to you. Feel free to use the first image as your sprite :)
- Increment ONLY - no need to remove tallies. Once they are scratched into a prison cell wall, they are there for life!
- Must post a link to a working demo on http://jsfiddle.net/
- Have fun!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fGYcd/)

```
$.fn.tallier = function () {
    var $this = this,
        bgUrl = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/96hvp.png',
        bgHeight = 125,
        bgVals = [
            [45, 25], // width, background-position X
            [65, -35],
            [85, -115],
            [105, -215],
            [140, -360]
        ],
        count = 0;

    $this.click(function(e) {
        count++;

        // add new tally box every 5th
        if (count%5 == 1) {
            var $newTally = $('<div>').addClass('tally');
            $newTally.css({
                          background: 'url("' + bgUrl + '") ' +
                            bgVals[0][1] + 'px 0 no-repeat transparent',
                          float: 'left',
                          width: bgVals[0][0] + 'px',
                          height: bgHeight + 'px'
                      });
            $this.append($newTally);
        }

        // change background position and width for new tally
        var $lastTally = $this.find('.tally:last'),
            i = count%5 - 1;
        i = i < 0 ? 4 : i;
        $lastTally.css({
            'background-position': bgVals[i][1] + 'px 0',
            width: bgVals[i][0] + 'px'
        });
    });
};

// invoke
$('#tally').tallier();
$('#tally').click();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fGYcd/)

Comment: +1 for way better new-line handling than mine..! =)

Answer (score 8):

Given the requirements, I've decided to use an `ol` as the container:

HTML:

```
<button id="tally">add another</button>
<ol id="count">
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
}

li:nth-child(5n) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(300deg);
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
    top: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

With the following jQuery:

```
$('#tally').click(
    function(){
        $('<li />').prop('class','tally').appendTo('#count');
        return false;
    });
```

[JS fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x8sxh/5/).

Comment: Thanks! ...though there's a bit of an implementation bug when the tally spreads over a new-line. Sigh. But it's too late to attend to that now, I'll just have to sleep, regardless of that shame... =b

Comment: I like it. Very clean and extensible.