# I want the tally marks to have 'minus tally' functionality so after adding erroneously they can be removed

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie that has used the tally mark answer to make a corona-virus python web app for my kids to do maths homework but I really want the option to remove tally marks for the kids when they over click.

The original post [JQuery challenge - draw tally marks on click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060015/jquery-challenge-draw-tally-marks-on-click-event/7060219#7060219?newreg=ad9e1380f14d46309aa5d3e089c98f9b) was a great eye  opener for me, and I was able to extend to using it for ones and tens, but I am not yet capable of redoing it for minus tally functionality.  What I want to do for this is add a button that invokes the remove of tallies in the same order they were added.

I was really hoping [mVChr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246616/mvchr) was around to give me some guidance as the author or someone equally as capable.

[The current web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdQyW.png)

Any help in these isolating but learning times would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have no idea how to provide an example other than the code for the original I have referenced that I am using as-is.

Comment: The links you have provided do not tell us what code you're using. Plus it's 8 years old. What libraries are you using? Please read the help article and it discusses how to provide proper example so others can help you.

Comment: I honestly don't understand much of this.
The links you have provided do not tell us what code you're using. Plus it's 8 years old. 
 The link provides all the source code I copied and am using so not sure what else I can add here as I don't really understand it much.
What libraries are you using? 
 Not sure what this means.  The link to the source code should answer this for a knowledgeable coder.
I am honestly doing my best but it seems the standards are too high for me, but I realyl want help to do things for my kids and to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example. There are other possible solutions.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xpy6dufv/37/

**HTML**

```
<div id="tally"></div>
<div class="remove btn">-</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#tally {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding-top: -3px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 3px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.fn.tallier = function(action) {
  var $this = this,
    bgUrl = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/96hvp.png',
    bgHeight = 125,
    bgVals = [
      [45, 25],
      [65, -35],
      [85, -115],
      [105, -215],
      [140, -360]
    ];

  if ($this.data("count") == undefined) {
    $this.data("count", 0);
  }

  var add = function() {
    $this.data("count", $this.data("count") + 1);
    var count = $this.data("count");
    if (count % 5 == 1) {
      var $newTally = $('<div>').addClass('tally');
      $newTally.css({
        background: 'url("' + bgUrl + '") ' +
          bgVals[0][1] + 'px 0 no-repeat transparent',
        float: 'left',
        width: bgVals[0][0] + 'px',
        height: bgHeight + 'px'
      });
      $this.append($newTally);
    }
    var $lastTally = $this.find('.tally:last'),
      i = count % 5 - 1;
    i = i < 0 ? 4 : i;
    $lastTally.css({
      'background-position': bgVals[i][1] + 'px 0',
      width: bgVals[i][0] + 'px'
    });
  };

  var sub = function() {
    if ($this.data("count") == 1) {
      return false;
    }
    $this.data("count", $this.data("count") - 1);
    var count = $this.data("count");
    var $lastTally = $this.find('.tally:last');
    if (count % 5 == 0) {
      $lastTally.remove();
    } else {
      var i = count % 5 - 1;
      i = i < 0 ? 4 : i;
      $lastTally.css({
        'background-position': bgVals[i][1] + 'px 0',
        width: bgVals[i][0] + 'px'
      });
    }
  };
  if (action == "add") {
    add();
  } else {
    sub();
  }
}

var $t = $('#tally');

$t.tallier("add");

$t.click(function() {
  $t.tallier("add");
});

$(".remove").click(function() {
  $t.tallier("sub");
});
```

The original script was designed to work as a Tally, each click increased the tally by 1. This uses the same algorithm yet adds a subtraction function.

Comment: Thanks Twisty that works great and I was able to get the instance integrated to the web page I have.  One question I have is if there is a limitation of running this multiple times on the page?  Will any of the variables get mixed up?

Comment: @Bigtoerag They should not since each is self contained within it's own function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarity.

Comment: I was motivated and got myself a JSfiddle account and put my final working solution online. https://jsfiddle.net/bigtoerag/39wx7pv1/